# Converting the formula into an Array google Sheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

Converting the below formula into an Array but its displaying the same result till last row can someone please resolve the bug.

=ARRAYFORMULA({"Stock";IF(B5:B="",, INDEX('Stock In by Invoices'!$J$5:$J,MATCH(1,('Stock In by Invoices'!$E$5:$E=C5:C)*('Stock In by Invoices'!$F$5:$F=D5:D)*('Stock In by Invoices'!$G$5:$G=E5:E),0)))})

Comment: Do you have an example sheet you can share?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jk8apMWz64S45LQZK033JBoPOPv-jnEn41kDEpLNMaw/edit#gid=1275095839 Here is the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Stock";IF(A2:A="",, VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C, {Stock!$A$2:$A&Stock!$B$2:$B&Stock!$C$2:$C, Stock!$D$2:$D}, 2, 0))})
```

and see if that works?